# Best way of resetting all variables project wide? --- (Java)

Tags: java, variables, reset

I'm a week into making a game at the moment, and I want to be able to "reset" the game. Make every variable revert back to its original value upon the start of the application.

Is there any built in method of accomplishing this task? I'm about 20 classes, and a few hundred variables in. I could make a reset() method in each class, and then call each method upon trying to reset.

Is there any easier way of doing this than that?

Comment: There is no way to do this other than explicitly providing a reset capability in your code.

Comment: just re-initialize your games object `game = new Game();`

Comment: If you want to make it complex, make a custom annotation, mark your classes with this annotation, list all the classes with this annotation, use reflection to reset attributes of those classes.

Comment: @Mitch Weaver Looks like you are not satisfied with the answers here. Are you still open for new solutions? I might have a solution for you.

Comment: If there's a better way of doing it then sure, I have already added an init() method to every class, then an init() method in my main class that calls all the others. It works fine of course, but it is a bit time consuming to write. What is your alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way: for every class, initialize all instance-variables you want to make "resettable" not in the constructor, but in a separate method (something like `initializeVariables()`) which you then call from the constructor. Like this, you can use this method anytime to reset all variales. Of course, you would have to do that for each class separately.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was talking about doing, was just wondering if there was any faster way of implementing this. I guess there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the fact that you write your game in Java for your advantage. If you want to "reset" you classes you can just re-initialize them like so

```
game.doSomething();
....
game = new Game();
```

Java will then take the old game and pass it through the GC, So basically you make your class constructor the `reset()` method (and why wouldn't it be? it's the constructors job).  you should also reset any other objects that spawn out of using `Game`. The neat thing about it is that you won't have to "remember" the default values when you modify your game objects.

If your game uses system resources (SQL connections, FileBuffers etc.) you will of course need to close them before resetting your game. in such case you could define a state in your game (without a view) that will be accessed when the user will reset the game.

This 'reset state' would be in charge of releasing system resources and will transit the user to the main menu state when it's done, you can also use this opportunity to save any data you want to persist.

Comment: The old game would still be in system memory though, correct? Would it ever get garbage collected if not = to null? Though that would be the best solution I think? Game game2 = new Game(); game1 = null;

Comment: the old game object will be garbage collected as long as it is not being referenced from anything or anywhere else in your project.